# Modified application.scss results in "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ," in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass

The situation is like this:

- I create a new Rails application (Rails 4.2.10 - Ruby 2.4.1)
- I generate a very simple scaffold with a couple of attributes
- I install the bootstrap gem following all the instructions [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem#a-ruby-on-rails).

Everything works until then, but when I try to use some extra css with `@import "some_css"` in `application.scss` I get the `"SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,"` error message in the view.

I have tried to put the `some_css` file both in the `app/assets` and `vendor` folders as well as include them in my html with both `stylesheet_link_tag` and pure html but the error persists.

This is the first time I get this error and it might be something very obvious in front of my eyes; in which case I apologise for my melted brains - I am in this dark place where there is no hope left.

Comment: Maybe related to Autoprefixer gem, https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails/issues/130

Comment: Is `@import` a `sass` directive (and not an `scss` directive)? Perhaps the problem is that you have `application.scss` and not `application.sass`? `some_css.sass` should probably go in `app/assets/stylesheets`, no?

Comment: @vzamanillo I tried following the suggestion from the last comment there but nothing changed. Should I downgrade below the "problematic" 7.2.4 version?

Comment: can you paste the contents of your `application.scss` ?  It could have to do with load order. Also the contents of your `some_css.scss` would be helpful to see.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna use the [bootstrap sass gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) instead:

In your gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.7'
```

Then in your `application.scss`

```
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'some_css';
```

Also see this if you need Bootstrap4  https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem#a-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

Look, I have worked with `scss` like this which taught me some remote instructor like at first on the `Gemfile`

```
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
```

then `bundle install` then renaming the `application.css` to `application.css.scss` or leave this as usual and create new custom `scss` file like `custom.css.scss` and on this

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "some_css";
```

and the `some_css` naming like this `_some_css.css` to start the file name with an underscore which is inside `stylesheets` folder or if you use another folder inside `stylesheets` folder like `stylesheets/modules` then while calling like this

```
@import "modules/some_css";
```

and attention to the files if unnecessary any symbols